# Firebase Auth system with Rails API design

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails, firebase

**TLDR; How can I utilize Firebase Auth in my iOS application and sync the Firebase ID with a user in my API?**

I am in the process of designing an iOS application that reads from a Rails API. When first coming up with the design, I wanted to use a pre-baked auth system so that I didn't have to design my own. Firebase provides Firestore which is a NoSQL database that I looked into at first and after seeing its limitations, at least from my view, it wasn't what I wanted. I landed on a Rails API with Postgres as it's what I am familiar with.

One issue I am running into is how I link a user created with Firebase and a user in my system. Right now, a user creates a user in my iOS application, it creates a user in Firebase with an FBID (Firebase ID), and if that is successful there is a callback that creates a user in my API and saves the Firebase ID under that user so I can link the two for relational data.

I see a downside here. If my API is down for some reason, and the firebase user gets created, it will be unable to make the API request to create a new user with that Firebase id in my API causing the app to function incorrectly.

This seems like only the beginning of the downsides. Curious about how others might look at this problem and come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this seems so hard is because you have introduced a [distributed transaction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction) to your system, which happens when utilizing [polyglot persistence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_persistence). Both operations need to succeed, or both need to fail. This is impossible when the two systems are isolated from one another, as in your Firebase and PosgreSQL implementation. There is no general purpose solution to this.

In it's simplest form, this involves writing additional error handing code. If inserting into Firebase fails, don't proceed with inserting data into PosgreSQL. Catch any exceptions thrown when inserting into PosgreSQL, and delete the data that was just inserted into Firebase.

Since you mention building a web API, it is worth mentioning micro services. Distributed transactions are replaced by [eventual consistency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). Applied to your problem, you could have three components. The first component would be a message queue. Registering a new user means publishing a message. After creating the user in Firebase, send a message to the queue with the necessary information. Another service would be subscribed to the "new user" topic, which would create a user profile record in PosgreSQL.

This certainly increases complexity, but the trade off is resilience. If the service feeding data into PosgreSQL goes down, new user messages pile up in the queue. When the service comes back up it starts reading the backed-up messages and retroactively creates records in PosgreSQL.

The downside of eventual consistency is that your application must gracefully handle situations where data exists in Firebase, but not yet in PosgreSQL. Again, we increase complexity to achieve this.

If you are only storing data in two places, I would recommend just storing it all in a relational database. Then you can use proper ACID transactions.

If you insist on using two different data stores, an extra try/catch around the insert into PosgreSQL is probably the best option. It is much easier to increase complexity later than it is to reduce it.